# need help understanding why this line in the code

Tags: javascript, jquery

this code in book [jQuery in action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182323) page 99

Why he wrote this line

***var current = this;***

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="greatgreatgrandpa">
    <head>
        <title>DOM Level 0 Bubbling Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/core.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jqia2.support.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $( function() {
                $('*').each( function() {
                    var current = this;
                    this.onclick = function(event) {
                        if (!event)
                            event = window.event;
                        var target = (event.target) ?
                        event.target : event.srcElement;
                        say('For ' + current.tagName + '#'+ current.id +
                        ' target is ' +
                        target.tagName + '#' + target.id);
                    };
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="greatgrandpa">
        <div id="grandpa">
            <div id="pops">
                <img id="example" src="example.jpg" alt="ooooh! ahhhh!"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He did that so that the `this` value could be preserved and used inside a nested lexical scope. Each function call to any function involves (internally) setting `this` to refer to some object, based on the details of the invocation.  Thus, inside a nested function (a function declared inside another function, as in this case), should there be a need to refer to the "outer" value of `this`, well, there's a problem: `this`, in that nested context, will have been set to refer to something else (not necessarily, but possibly).  By "capturing" `this` in the outer context, that inner code will be able to refer to it freely.

That's a pretty good book by the way; I used to work with one of the authors (Bear) :-)

Comment: thanks but he wrote 'current.tagName' and wrote 'target.tagName' There is no difference between them

Comment: @tarek11011 but they **are** different - "target" is a reference to the element that was the direct target of the event, while "current" is a reference to the element to which the event handler function was attached. That's kind-of the whole point of the example - it's a demonstration of how event bubbling works. The browser will "walk" up the DOM from the original target, invoking handlers on every parent element.  When the handlers are called there, then "target" and "current" will not be the same.

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers are correct; I just try to make it easier to understand.

`this` is assigned by context. If a function is called as part of event handling, `this` is assigned to the DOM element which fired the event. In the example above, that would be the element that was clicked.

In a similar way, `this` in the loop `$('*').each()` is the current element in the DOM (the element which matched the selector `'*'`).

This means `this` is changed by the browser before a function is called. If you want to use the outer `this` in the inner click handler, you must create a reference to it. The reference keeps its value because the browser will make a *copy* of all visible variables when it creates the inner click handler.

This also means that `current` will be a different reference for all inner click handlers. For each handler, it will point to the value the outer `this` had when the click handler was created.

Answer (score 1):

Because within the function defined for onclick, `this` refers to the object the event has fired on, so to refer to the `this` outside of that block of code, you must assign it to something else first.

Answer (score 1):

Look inside the function defined for onclick.  The meaning of `this` is different inside that function, as it's set when the function is run.

By doing `var current = this` it stores a copy of the current value of `this` so it can be used inside that nested function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code's aim is to be able to use the value of `this` in the  `this.onclick = function(event) { }` function, as in this function `this` would refer to the DOM element that was clicked on.